# Category navigation on left side

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi have download the [sidebar navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-sidebar-navigation-2.html)

[image]

As you can see in the picture the works fine ... but this extencion only appear  when i search for a product or in the category navigation ... i want this extencion on my home page

i want to see my home page in the same way that you are seeing my result of search

desing with columns its by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Homepage is actually a CMS page. Go to `CMS > Pages` then edit your homepage. Click on the `Design` tab, add something like this in the `Layout Update XML`:

```
 <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```